# How to resolve inner methods are not supported. Method definition not expected here. explodeAar

Tags: android, opencv, nativescript

after successfully importing openCV modules into nativescript android app on android studio, keep getting startup failed error which points to explodeArr in app gradle

tried migrating to androidx , still got error
tried creating a new class according to Groovy documentation , still got error

task runSbg(type: JavaExec) {
        dependsOn "collectAllJars"
        if (!findProject(':static-binding-generator').is(null)) {
            dependsOn ':static-binding-generator:jar'
        }

```
    outputs.dir("$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen")
    inputs.dir(INPUT_JS_DIR)
    inputs.dir(extractedDependenciesDir)

    workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
    main "-jar"
    args "static-binding-generator.jar"

    doFirst {
        new File("$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen").deleteDir()
    }
}

task ensureMetadataOutDir {
    doLast {
        def outputDir = file("$METADATA_OUT_PATH")
        outputDir.mkdirs()
    }
}

        def explodeAar(File compileDependency, File outputDir) {
            logger.info("explodeAar: Extracting ${compileDependency.path} 
          -> ${outputDir.path}")

            if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".aar")) {
                java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new 
                java.util.jar.JarFile(compileDependency)
                Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries()
                while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) 
                    enumEntries.nextElement()
                    if (file.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
                        def targetFile = new File(outputDir, file.name)
                        InputStream inputStream = jar.getInputStream(file)
                        new File(targetFile.parent).mkdirs()
                        Files.copy(inputStream, targetFile.toPath(), 
                     StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    }
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        continue
                    }
                }
                jar.close()
            } else if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
                copy {
                    from compileDependency.absolutePath
                    into outputDir
                }
            }
        }


def md5(String string) {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digest.update(string.bytes);
    return new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(32, '0');
}
```

I expected a  completed build 
but, instead get : startup failed:
build file '...android/app/build.gradle': 473: Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. at line: 
               def explodeAar(File compileDependency, File outputDir) {
               ^

Comment: this might have been an extra bracket, I had a similar issue today.